# Does Visual Studio 2012 Professional not really exist?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

After installing VS2012 Professional as Administrator, successfully, according to the congratulatory message from the install package, there's no devenv.exe in the Common7\IDE folder and no entry in the Start menu.

Looking for technical support on the Microsoft site, I don't see Visual Studio 2012 Professional [listed there](https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?Gprid=1117&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn&wfxredirect=1). Has it been renamed to "Premium" perhaps?

```
Select the product that your question or problem relates to.
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Standard Edition
Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition
Microsoft Visual C# 2005 Express Edition
Microsoft Visual J# 2005 Express Edition
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2005 Express Edition
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition
Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Academic Edition
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Premium (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer Everywhere 2010 (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012 (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2013 (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 (All Languages)
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows (All Languages)
```

Comment: Hmmm... Visual Studio 2012 Professional is a real thing: http://i.imgur.com/UTODXYt.png

Comment: It is, but it's still a quite funny question, isn't it? :)

Comment: Tim - did you get the fat "LAUNCH" button after installing? Which would let you start it up. If not, check the list of "Features and Programs" in the Control Panel to see if Visual Studio 2012 is listed there or not.

Comment: I don't recall a fat LAUNCH button, Per. When I check the Programs and Features listing, Visual Studio 2012 Professional is not listed there, although my copy of VS2010 is there.  Is there any chance that .NET4.5's clobbering of 4.0 has caused Microsoft to make the installation a mere Installation Simulation?

Comment: @Steven V: How do I know that you're not from The Adjustment Bureau?

Comment: LOL. I tried the vs_professional.exe download approach, and this time there was a fat LAUNCH button. But when I launched VS2012, there was a warning message that it was incompatible with "this version of Windows". I'm running Windows 7 x64. Applying patch KB2781514 now.